# How can i use SqlDataReader using Java?

Tags: java, c#, sqldatareader

I am new to java programming. How can i use SqlDataReader in Java. Basically i have programmed on C#. Now i am trying to convert into java because of project need. Below you can find my C# code.

```
     DataTable dt = new DataTable();
     con.Open();
     SqlDataReader myReader;
     SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select First_name from Table_1 Where 
     Access = Access_withdraw order by Time", con);
     myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
     count = 0;

                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        output[count] = myReader["First_name"].ToString();
                        count = count + 1;
                    }

                    Button1.Text = output[0]; 
                    Button2.Text = output[1];
```

How can i attain SqlDatareader in Java syntax. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think there is a class called SQLDataReader in JDK. You could look at this example to understand the Java syntax to connect to db and execute the query. https://www.javatpoint.com/example-to-connect-to-the-mysql-database

Comment: Are you using Java or Javascript?  Please only use the relevant tags.  Edit your post and remove any unneeded tags.

Comment: What you mean `Java syntax`?

Comment: Thank you. I would change the tag. Can someone help me in converting this c# code to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SqlDataReader doesnt exist on Java.
You can use :
PreparedStatement and then ResultSet:

I guess you can resolve your code migration with this example.

```
int id=12;
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from table where id=?");  
//You can set query parameters
ps.setInt(1,id);
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();     
while(rs.next()){  
//Get parameters 
int num=rs.getInt(1);  
}
```

In conclusion, `Resulset` its the java `SQLDataReader`